# Changing nested list of numbers to nested list o tuples

Tags: python-2.7

please can someone help me with the codes for this nested list of numbers to look like the nested list of tuples below ie from pot to val.

```
pot = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]

val = [[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)],[(5,6),(6,7),(7,8)]]
```

I used a grouper function but it didn't quite give me the desired result. Is there another way ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for line in pot:
    temp = []
    for i in range(len(line)-1):
        temp.append( (line[i],line[i+1]) )
    val.append(temp)
```

May contain typos.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a better way to do it but I noticed there was no answer to your question and worked something out that does the job:

```
pot = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
val = []

for sublist in pot:
    temp = []
    for n in range (1, len(sublist)):
        temp.append((sublist[n-1], sublist[n]))
    val.append(temp)

print val
```

prints

```
[[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)], [(5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to Python.  Just started learning it because I'm working on a project that requires is, but I think this solves your question.

```
pot = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
inner = []
val = []
a = 0
b = 0

for L in pot:
    for x in range(len(L)):
    if x>0:
        a = L[x-1]
        b = L[x]
        inner.append((a,b))
    val.append(inner)
    inner = []
print val
```

My output running python 2.7 is:

```
[[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)], [(5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8)]]
```